# Smooth volume change with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

javascript newbie here. So I've been messing around with the Web Audio API trying to figure stuff out and I found that exponentialRampToValueAtTime does just what I want except it only seems to do it once(?)
Take this generic code:

```
context = new AudioContext();
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
contextGain = context.createGain();
oscillator.type = 'sine';
oscillator.frequency = 440
oscillator.connect(contextGain);
contextGain.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.start(0);
```

contextGain.gain.value = 1 by default so if I run `contextGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.1,context.currentTime + 2)` it drops nice and smoothly from 1 to 0.1. But if I try to get it back at 1, say `contextGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1,context.currentTime + 2)` it instead jumps suddenly to 1. Why does this happen? Is there any way I can do this ramp as many times as I want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setValueAtTime()` first to mark beginning of a change:

```js
contextGain.gain.setValueAtTime(contextGain.gain.value, context.currentTime);
contextGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.1, context.currentTime + 2);
```

Without this, your gradual change starts in the past.

This is needed because the gradual change of an audio param starts from the *previous event*. That previous event is a previous gain change using the methods `setValueAtTime()`, `linearRampToValueAtTime()`, `exponentialRampToValueAtTime()`, etc.

Quote from the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/exponentialRampToValueAtTime):

> The `exponentialRampToValueAtTime()` method of the `AudioParam` Interface schedules a gradual exponential change in the value of the `AudioParam`. **The change starts at the time specified for the *previous event***, follows an exponential ramp to the new value given in the `value` parameter, and reaches the new value at the time given in the `endTime` parameter.

Here is small demo:

```js
var context = new AudioContext();
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
var gain = context.createGain();
oscillator.type = 'sine';
oscillator.frequency = 440
oscillator.connect(gain);
gain.connect(context.destination);

document.getElementById('bplay').addEventListener('click', function() {
  context.resume();
  oscillator.start(0);
  gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0.01, context.currentTime);
  gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, context.currentTime + 2);
});

document.getElementById('bdown').addEventListener('click', function() {
  gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(context.currentTime);
  gain.gain.setValueAtTime(gain.gain.value, context.currentTime);
  gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.01, context.currentTime + 2);
});

document.getElementById('bup').addEventListener('click', function() {
  gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(context.currentTime);
  gain.gain.setValueAtTime(gain.gain.value, context.currentTime);
  gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, context.currentTime + 2);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="bplay">Play</button>
<button type="button" id="bdown">Volume down</button>
<button type="button" id="bup">Volume up</button>
```